# Out of Server Memory when reconciling a large edit session in ArcObjects

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, oracle-spatial

One of our users has been periodically experiencing `Out of Server Memory` errors with ArcSDE 10.0 when trying to reconcile a large edit session.

[image: ArcObjects error -2147216115]
[image: ArcObjects error -2147216115]

VMware ESX Instance:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- Service Pack 1
- Intel Xeon E5-2660 @ 2.20GHz
- 8 GB RAM

I've set up a performance monitor to track memory usage but I'm curious if this is a problem anybody else has experienced with versioned editing?

Our RDBMS is Oracle and I have found this page by ESRI:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002n00000026000000

However, this seems to assume that ArcSDE and Oracle are on the same machine (for us they are not). Should I remove the 'unlimited' table space associated with the editing user?

Also, we make direct connections to your database using the Oracle client. Does this mean that I'm perhaps looking at the wrong server (ArcSDE) and should be speaking with the DBAs ? I'm thinking ArcObjects error means ArcSDE problem but perhaps somebody can correct me on this?

---

Solution seemed to be to enable 64-bit background GP on the desktop who was responsible for editing. Large edit sessions seemed to cause problems with our Oracle Geodatabase. Likely could have been resolved at the RDBMS level but DBAs were unavailable at the time to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with large polygon datasets, you should try installing 64-bit background geoprocessing. This allows arcgis desktop to use more of the machine's ram to execute the task.(see link below)
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm.

Information needed to better answer this question are as follows:

- How big is the file you are performing geoprocessing on?
- Are you doing the geoprocessing using Arcgis server or desktop?
- Does this error not happen on non-versioned edits?

Comment: At first reading this appears to be more of a comment than an answer,  and you should consider rewording.  Rather than bullets it would be better to tailor the answer, to something like, if you are working on large datasets on arcgis desktop with non-versioned  edits then...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This was in fact exactly what we did. To answer you questions: Large - we were trying to merge edits on a 100k+ line table. ArcGIS Desktop was doing the GP but the problem seemed related only to the edit session. Versioned, yes.